# embed 3rd party EXE on the simple vb.net form

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have 3rd party EXE and i want to embed into simple vb.net form .
i was try many kind of method but i can't accomplish .
this is what i done until now.
if anyone who can help me ..much appreciate!
thanks you
this is full source.
and it working well.
firstly should have to add EXE file into Resource tab in project
project -> property -> resource

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    ' I am using a Button to call the Resources.Test file. You can edit it to fit your need.
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Draq you EXE file to your Project > Resources and it will be saved as a RAW file.
        Dim SetupPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\project3.exe"
        Using sCreateMSIFile As New FileStream(SetupPath, FileMode.Create)
            sCreateMSIFile.Write(My.Resources.Project3, 0, My.Resources.Project3.Length)
        End Using
        Process.Start(SetupPath)
    End Sub
    Public Function MyProcessRunning(ByVal name As String) As Boolean
        'Check if the process is runing. As ERROR handler.
        For Each CloseMyProcess As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
            If CloseMyProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith(name) Then
                'process found running!!! 
                Return False
            End If
        Next
        'process not found, So it is finaly been killed!!!
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Please replace "thank you notes" with exact problem you have with code (errors messages, compile errors, unexpected behavior...)

Comment: here is what i try to embed file..if need pls download . thanks so much  https://anonfiles.com/file/4d2fba905d7b18c3f670c6c3f7ebdd44

Comment: Nobody likes EXE files appearing from no-where.  UAC and the user's anti-malware will put a stop to that.  If you want to write an installer then you are going to have to ask for elevation.  Don't write your own installer, you won't get the uninstall correct.  Use an installer creation utility instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below and make sure you add the .exe as a reference inside your project

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(
    ByVal sender As System.Object,
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Filename.exe")
    Dim BytesToWrite() As Byte = My.Resources.ColorCop
    Dim FileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(FileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim BinaryWriter As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(FileStream)
    BinaryWriter.Write(BytesToWrite)
    BinaryWriter.Close()
    FileStream.Close()
    Process.Start(FileName)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you using an MDI container?

Comment: hello yes..i also can use MDI it no problem .important thing is..make exe inside vb.net

Comment: What do you mean "make exe inside vb.net" or "make exe run inside form"? Your post says that you have code that is running well - not clear what is your problem than... May be if you give an example of similar behavior in well know programs someone may be able to help you. Or describe more precisely what you want. Maybe you are reinventing [OLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding)?

Comment: exactly right ! i want to use function like OLE container. someone asked in here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86af9be3-bc6a-49f2-9943-71a30fd43107/how-to-achieve-ole-control-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral  such like ole i want to use together EXE. sorry my bad english!